# Are any ranger pets ranged themselves?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Are any ranger pets ranged themselves?  I'm wondering if there are any pets that will not run into melee range.  Melee pets in WvW seems like it would not be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Pet Guide](http://gw2.mmorpg-life.com/ranger-pets-guide/1923/) here, the Devourers are ranged pets.

Answer (score 3):

Devourers and Spiders are ranged.